# Android, RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and ImageView as cell content does not fit the vertical space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to implement a simple grid of images.

Each image is the same size, the problem is that if I scale down the images (for example if I set a spanCount so that the gridlayout has to resize images to fit them) the "virtual-cell" that contains the image does not adapt to image size.

Here you can see the differences between spanCount=3 and spanCount=4.

[image][image]

If I use `fitXY` for the imageView this is the result, so the grid layout manager reduces the cell width but does not fit the cell height.

[image]

My grid layout xml:

```
       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="4"
            tools:itemCount="30"
            tools:listitem="@layout/image_item" />
```

And image_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

My targets:

- STEP 1: remove the gap between columns
- STEP 2: resize the images so that they always fit the horizontal space (in this example with spanCount = 3 a small space is visible on the right)

To be more clear, I need to remove the space marked red.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may try answering this, in your `image_item.xml` I would suggest you change the layout width to `match_parent` like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

The logic behind this is since we already using GridLayout manager and our spanCount is 4, so the `match_parent` width will occupy all the space available to it, inside whatever spanCount is assigned.

Secondly `centerCrop` would be better I feel. It can automatically adjust all your images without them looking stretched.

EDIT:
I feel you can get this done using the magic of ConstraintLayout, you will have to update your `image_item.xml` as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The logic here being the 0dp with GridLayout helps your image to occupy whatever width is available and `dimensionRatio` being one helps your width and height match equally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I cannot lose part of the image so this is not a viable solution. I just need to adjust the height of the "cell", this behavior is totally unexpected to me.

Comment: @blow How about if you keep the width to `match_parent` only and remove the scale type? I feel like that should solve your issue, unless I am misunderstanding. Could you clarify me on your end goal here?

Comment: My goal is to remove the black gap between images, as you can see in the second image there is space between "rows".

Comment: @blow I have updated the answer. You may try using that. From what I understand this should be what you need.

Comment: It works very well thank you. So the only value I have to calculate is the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` based on the real size of the images, right?

Comment: @blow Glad to help and correct, I did not know the original size of your image, so I just made it `1` for now. 
You can easily find out the ratio as you said all of your images are sized equally, so basically it will be width divided by the height as in width/height.

Comment: @blow `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` also directly accepts the ratio too, like you could assign it as `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"`. You can check the documentation for properties. Further I remember you can specify the ratio is according to the height or the width.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you are being affected by `spanCount` and `ItemCoun`t together with `fitCenter`. To solve the problem do this.

1. Go to gridLayoutManager and specify the number of cells you want in your gridLayoutManager.
2. Open your image_item.xml specify the width to `match_parent` and then you must specify the height e.g. 100dp. Don't do wrap content since images will be of different size and we are doing this to force the size of the cells to be equal so that each and every image to fit in the same manner.
3. In your ImageView `declare (android:scaleType="centerCrop")` don't forget to remove spanCount, ItemCount and fitCenter.

Now this should work fine if everything is good on the Java side.